# Error when installing Subkey (Substrate Developer Hub)

Tags: linux, substrate

I am new to substrate and programming and I am constantly running into the same error when trying installing subkey to generate some keys for a node. I have tried to install subkey following the step in the Substrate Developer Hub but I am not being able to complete the installation. The error is the following:

```
error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:51:25
|
51 | const MASK: u8 = Self::BITS - 1;
| ^^^^ multiple BITS found
|
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait BitMemory
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:44:2
|
44 | const BITS: u8 = mem::size_of::() as u8 * 8;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in the trait IsNumber
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/funty-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:144:2
|
144 | const BITS: u32;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #1
|
51 | const MASK: u8 = BitMemory::BITS - 1;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #2
|
51 | const MASK: u8 = IsNumber::BITS - 1;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/order.rs:291:15
|
291 | if ct == R::BITS {
| ^^^^ multiple BITS found
|
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait BitMemory
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:44:2
|
44 | const BITS: u8 = mem::size_of::() as u8 * 8;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in the trait IsNumber
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/funty-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:144:2
|
144 | const BITS: u32;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #1
|
291 | if ct == BitMemory::BITS {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #2
|
291 | if ct == IsNumber::BITS {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/order.rs:339:15
|
339 | if ct == R::BITS {
| ^^^^ multiple BITS found
|
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait BitMemory
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:44:2
|
44 | const BITS: u8 = mem::size_of::() as u8 * 8;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in the trait IsNumber
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/funty-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:144:2
|
144 | const BITS: u32;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #1
|
339 | if ct == BitMemory::BITS {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #2
|
339 | if ct == IsNumber::BITS {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/order.rs:450:19
|
450 | for n in 0 .. R::BITS {
| ^^^^ multiple BITS found
|
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait BitMemory
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:44:2
|
44 | const BITS: u8 = mem::size_of::() as u8 * 8;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in the trait IsNumber
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/funty-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:144:2
|
144 | const BITS: u32;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #1
|
450 | for n in 0 .. BitMemory::BITS {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #2
|
450 | for n in 0 .. IsNumber::BITS {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/order.rs:469:21
|
469 | pos.value() < R::BITS,
| ^^^^ multiple BITS found
|
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait BitMemory
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:44:2
|
44 | const BITS: u8 = mem::size_of::() as u8 * 8;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in the trait IsNumber
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/funty-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:144:2
|
144 | const BITS: u32;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #1
|
469 | pos.value() < BitMemory::BITS,
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #2
|
469 | pos.value() < IsNumber::BITS,
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0034]: multiple applicable items in scope
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/order.rs:476:7
|
476 | R::BITS,
| ^^^^ multiple BITS found
|
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait BitMemory
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bitvec-0.20.1/src/mem.rs:44:2
|
44 | const BITS: u8 = mem::size_of::() as u8 * 8;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: candidate #2 is defined in the trait IsNumber
--> /home/centifuge/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/funty-1.2.0/src/lib.rs:144:2
|
144 | const BITS: u32;
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #1
|
476 | BitMemory::BITS,
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: disambiguate the associated constant for candidate #2
|
476 | IsNumber::BITS,
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 60 previous errors
```

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0034, E0308.
For more information about an error, try rustc --explain E0034.
error: failed to compile subkey v2.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate#e03ca38d), intermediate artifacts can be found at /tmp/cargo-installkvO14R

Caused by:
could not compile bitvec

Comment: This is a Rust dependency problem not specific to Substrate.
See e.g. [here](https://github.com/bitvecto-rs/bitvec/issues/105#issuecomment-778570981)

Comment: In case you're using the install instructions from the developer hub, here is the corrected version:
`cargo install --force subkey --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate --version 2.0.0 --locked` (add --locked at the end to lock the dependencies)

Comment: I face same issue. Did you find the way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue at my end

```
cargo install --force subkey --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate --tag=v3.0.0 --locked
```